# 10.6 PHD file type exclusion

Tags: snow-leopard, data-synchronization, network

I manage an environment that uses portable home directories for users with 10.6 for both the client and server. I've setup syncing via Workgroup Manager of pretty much entire home directories except for `~/Movies` and `~/Music` directories.

Unfortunately  I have a particular user that insists on downloading a **lot** of media (movies, tv shows) on the company provided laptop and leaving it in hierarchical folders on the Desktop, which then syncs multiple gigs every day to our fileserver when she gets on site.

How do I specify the exclusion of .avi and .mkv file extensions within just the `~/Desktop` directory using Workgroup Manager?

Comment: Do you ever intend on **.avi** or **.mkv** files to be synced regardless of the directory?

Comment: Probably not for this user, so excluding it entirely would be useful in this case. But we do have some where we will need to exclude .avi files in specific directories.

Comment: Unfortunately the following answer is not yet tested as I do not currently have access to test it. If it does not work as expected I will remove or edit my post accordingly. It has been awhile since I used mobile account with WGM.

Comment: Was the answer I provided helpful?

Comment: I just realized the the ~/Desktop/*.avi was not appearing correctly in my answer. :–(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you never intend on .avi or .mkv files to be synced you may want to try the following.

1. **Mobile Pane**
2. **Skip items that match any of the following**
3. Choose **Name Contains** and type "**.avi**" (without quotes).

   - Do the same for "**.mkv**" (without quotes).

If you do intend on syncing both file types and would like only to stop them from syncing when they are found within the Desktop folder you may want to try the following.

1. **Mobile Pane**
2. **Skip items that match any of the following**
3. Choose **Full Path** and type "~/Desktop/*

   .avi" (without quotes)

   - Do the same for "~/Desktop/

   *.mkv" (without quotes)

Comment: I tested your first answer to exclude .avi and .mkv files entirely and it worked flawlessly for me. I haven't had a chance to check the second solution yet, but I'm not sure if that will work .avi files in nested directories.

Comment: @anglachel Glad to here it. It has been awhile since I used PHD. :–)

Comment: Great, folder selective exclusions work too! Thanks!

Comment: @anglachel Great :–)